# PyQt - Show another Window after correct pass

Tags: python, pyqt

I made simple to forms. one is for the login and the other the main window after enter correct code
i used for this the show() method but when i enter the correct code the main window pops up and close instantly ...

```
def check(self):

    if self.lineEdit.text() == "xoxo":
        MainMenu = Window2()
        MainMenu.show()
        print("You are in")

    else:
        print("Wr0ng")
        self.lineEdit.clear()
```

i dont know why it closed directly?

Comment: change `MainMenu`  to `self.MainMenu`

Comment: -.- oh lol ... -.- yes this i didnt see .... thank you